# Load a modal if a session exists is not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, bootstrap-modal

I want show a modal if session is exist, I am tried like this but it's not showing

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['Message1'])) { ?>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Welcome...</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    This is test 
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
   </div>
  </div> 
 </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(window).load(function(){        
  $('#myModal').modal('show');
}); 
</script>
<?php } ?>
```

Thanx in advance

Comment: What do you see? What does the console output? Have you included the bootstrap script and css?

Comment: Please define "_it's not working_".

Comment: if(!empty($_SESSION['Message1'])) use this instead of isset().

Comment: Still not showing modal

Comment: Once remove the session condition and check whether it shows. May be there is other problem then session. Also check whether modal loaded in html or not.

Comment: Make sure you called `session_start();` at the top of your codes.

Comment: I remove the session condition then modal is open on load

Comment: I resolve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you.

Instead of  `$(window).load()` try

```
$( "#myModal" ).load(function() {
  $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

Comment: Do you try juts without any load  ` $('#myModal').modal('show');` ?

Comment: Also look at this answer maybe it will help you
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36672567/4553685

Comment: how I see there is a `aria-hidden="true"` in the `<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">`
can you remove that and try again

Answer (score 0):

you just forgot to started the session.
so just added this line before you checked the session.

```
session_start();
```

Comment: session_start(); is added in my page but I forgot to add in my question

Comment: hi just remove `$(window).load(function(){`