# Button Load with ajax request but click event dont show up the model with ajax success function data

Tags: javascript, jquery

from my php page searching employee retrieve by ajax success function and displayed as button ! when i click on fetched button it works like post request 200 ok! but modal dont show up and not even  updated with my new ajax request result !! 
 I want to display searched  employees information via modal! 
i have tried many approach!
click function, on click function, delegate function does not work!

click function, on click function, delegate function does not work! 
even  clcik event on parent element

button fetched by this request

```
 $("#searchEmployeeForm").on('submit',(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
        if ( $("#selectCompany").val()!="" || $("#selectDepartment").val()!="" || $("#selectDesignation").val()!="" || $("#searchByName").val()!="" || $("#searchByID").val()!=""){
            $.ajax({
          url: "controller/employee/find_Employee.php", 
          type: "POST",  
                 // Type of request to be send, called as method
          data: new FormData(this), 
          contentType: false,  
            dataType: 'json',     
          cache: false,             
          processData:false,       
          success: function(data)   
          {

               $('#listOfEmployee').empty();
             $.each(data, function (i, empdetail) {
                        console.log(empdetail);



          $('#listOfEmployee').append("<button class='list-group-item  d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center viewEmployeeData' id= "+ empdetail.emp_id +">"+ empdetail.first_name + empdetail.last_name + "</button>" );

 });

          console.log("data:" + data);

          }
          });

               }
               else{
                  alert("Field Can not be Empty ");

               }       

     }));
```

button on click event

```
$(document).on('click', '.viewEmployeeData', function (e){
          e.preventDefault();
          console.log('limon ');


   var employee_id = $(this).attr("id");  
     alert(employee_id);

           if(employee_id)  
           {  
                $.ajax({  
                     url:"controller/employee/employee_info.php",  
                     method:"POST",  
                    dataType: 'json',
                     data:{employee_id:employee_id},  
                     success:function(data){  

                          $('.modal-title').html(data.firs_name);
                            $('#view_employee_data_modal').modal("show");  
                          alert(data);

                     }  
                });  
           }      
});
```

i expected  button click event will display modal with my ajax request data!
NB: click event works but only its console.log and alert modal dont show up after ajax success function.

Answer (score 0):

when ajax success return data and add in dom and that dom event can not bind directly so you bind event in main dom it mean return data fill in "**listOfEmployee**" dom here event bint so work perfectly.

```
$('#listOfEmployee').on('click','.viewEmployeeData',function(e){
              e.preventDefault();
              console.log('limon ');


       var employee_id = $(this).attr("id");  
         alert(employee_id);

               if(employee_id)  
               {  
                    $.ajax({  
                         url:"controller/employee/employee_info.php",  
                         method:"POST",  
                        dataType: 'json',
                         data:{employee_id:employee_id},  
                         success:function(data){  

                              $('.modal-title').html(data.firs_name);
                                $('#view_employee_data_modal').modal("show");  
                              alert(data);

                         }  
                    });  
               }      
    });
```

Comment: No Sir Its not working! modal dont show up ! but alert and console.log ok !
and in ajax request status code 200 ok but do not previewing anything.

Comment: model(show) not working lower version boostrap and jquery.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36672304/bootstrap-mymodal-modalshow-is-not-working reference link

Comment: still getting same issue :(

Comment: jquery and boostrap version share so i will check

Comment: jQuery v3.4.1 
Bootstrap v4.3.1
Thank you for your consideration