# TypeError: c(...)(...).modal is not a function after built vue-cli project

Tags: jquery, webpack, vuejs2, materialize, vue-cli-4

I'm new in vuejs. 
I'm working in vue project using vue-cli

- I installed vue vue/cli with `npm install -g @vue/cli`
- I created a project with `vue init webpack my-project`
- I installed jQuery with `npm install jquery`
- I installed materialize-css with `npm install materialize-css`
- Everything is fine after `npm run dev`
- But when I do `npm run buid` and I run the index.html file which is in dist directory I get this error in chrome devtools

```
Uncaught TypeError: c(...)(...).modal is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (App.vue:20)
    at l (jquery.js:3557)
    at d (jquery.js:3625)
```

My main.js

```
// The Vue build version to load with the `import` command
// (runtime-only or standalone) has been set in webpack.base.conf with an alias.
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'
import vueResource from 'vue-resource'
import store from './components/store/AuthStore'
import 'materialize-css'
import 'materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css'

let currentUrl = window.location.href
let url = new URL(currentUrl)
let tokenFromUrl = url.searchParams.get('token')
let nameFromUrl = url.searchParams.get('name')
let avatarFromUrl = url.searchParams.get('avatar_link')

if (tokenFromUrl) {
  localStorage.setItem('token', tokenFromUrl)
  localStorage.setItem('name', nameFromUrl)
  localStorage.setItem('avatar_link', avatarFromUrl)
}

let token = localStorage.getItem('token') ? localStorage.getItem('token') : ''

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.prototype.$hostname = (Vue.config.productionTip) ? 'https://ipaq-mobile.000webhostapp.com/traitement' : 'http://127.0.0.1:8000'
Vue.prototype.$avatar_link = localStorage.getItem('avatar_link')
Vue.use(vueResource)
Vue.http.options.root = (Vue.config.productionTip) ? 'https://ipaq-mobile.000webhostapp.com/traitement/api' : 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api'
Vue.http.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Origin, Accept, Authorisation'
Vue.http.headers.common['Accept'] = 'application/json'
Vue.http.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  store,
  components: { App },
  template: '<App/>'
})
```

My App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="navbar">
      <router-view name="navbar" v-bind:pathName="pathName"/>
          <!-- <div @click="loadMore = !loadMore"><h1><a>loadMore</a></h1></div> -->
    </div>
    <SideNav></SideNav>
    <router-view name="main"></router-view>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import SideNav from './components/TheSideNav'
import $ from 'jquery'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  mounted: function () {
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('.modal').modal()
      $('.sidenav').sidenav()
    })
  },
  components: {
    SideNav
  },
  computed: {
    pathName () {
      return this.$route.name
    }
  }
}

</script>

<style>

</style>
```

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Your included jquery lib seems to be lacking `modal()`. Maybe this will lead you in the right direction https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36672304

Comment: Thanks for your reply but stackoverflow.com/questions/36672304 haven't helped me.

Answer (score 0):

You need a http server, such as nginx.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I just tried it on a nginx server and i still got the same error.

Comment: I didn't see any 'server' segment in your conf file, you need to configure nginx correctly first.

Answer (score 0):

I had this code in my build/webpack.dev.conf.js

```
 new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery',
      'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
    })
```

which were not in build/webpack.prod.conf.js so I have added it.